# R dev.copy() with non-GUI devices for batch graphic scripts

Tags: r, graphics, plot, batch-processing

'dev.copy' copies the graphics contents of the current device to the device specified. If the current device is:

```
windows() # or perhaps X11
plot(1:10)
dev.copy(device=pdf,file='hello.pdf') 
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

With this approach we can copy the same plot to multiple devices (formats).

What if the source device is a non-GUI one? I would like to copy plot in many formats in batch mode, therefore_without showing GUI windows_to the user.
But:

```
png()    # or other non-GUI devs
plot(1:10)
dev.copy(device=pdf,file='hello.pdf') 
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

doesn't work. In fact the device remains empty until it is closed but, when closed, it is not available for copy anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `dev.control('enable')`. From `?dev.copy`:

> dev.copy copies the graphics contents of the current device to the
>   device specified...(If recording is off on the current device, there
>   are no contents to copy: this will result in no plot or an empty
>   plot.) ... The displaylist can be turned on and off using dev.control.
>   Initially recording is on for screen devices, and off for print
>   devices.